# Receiving an error via Force.com Migration Tool for a simple deployment of metadata. Thoughts?

Tags: metadata-api, migration-tool

Here's the error:

> All Component Failures
>
> 1. package.xml -- Error: No package.xml found
> 2. package.xml -- Error: Bad file:Unexpected element < http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata > members during simple type deserialization

I have:

1. Updated my `ant-Salesforce.jar` to the most up-to-date version (35)
2. `Build.properties` This has all the necessary credentials.
3. `Build.xml` Has all the appropriate targets
4. **codepkg** directory which contains:

   - `package.xml`
   - **objects** directory, which contains:

     - `Account.object'

My `package.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

<types>
<members>Account<members>
<name>CustomObject</name>
</types>

<version>35.0</version>
</Package>
```

My `Account.object` file with some search layouts connected to the object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <searchLayouts>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.NAME</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.ADDRESS1_STREET</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.ADDRESS1_CITY</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.ADDRESS1_STATE</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.ADDRESS1_ZIP</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.PHONE1</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <customTabListAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.RECORDTYPE</customTabListAdditionalFields>
        <lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.NAME</lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.ADDRESS1_CITY</lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.ADDRESS1_STATE</lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.PHONE1</lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.RECORDTYPE</lookupDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <lookupPhoneDialogsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.NAME</lookupPhoneDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <lookupPhoneDialogsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.ADDRESS1_CITY</lookupPhoneDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <lookupPhoneDialogsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.ADDRESS1_STATE</lookupPhoneDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <lookupPhoneDialogsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.PHONE1</lookupPhoneDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <lookupPhoneDialogsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.RECORDTYPE</lookupPhoneDialogsAdditionalFields>
        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.NAME</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.ADDRESS1_CITY</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.ADDRESS1_STATE</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.PHONE1</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
        <searchResultsAdditionalFields>ACCOUNT.RECORDTYPE</searchResultsAdditionalFields>
    </searchLayouts>
</CustomObject>
```

Lastly, it hangs in "Pending" mode whenever i deploy. Any help would be appreciated. I'm really new at this, and just getting hte hang of it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both errors are caused by a syntax error in the package.xml file.  You forgot to close the `<members>` tag with `</members>` :)

Regarding the Pending status, that might mean that another deployment is running against the org.  Check the Deployment Status under Setup.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is not high enough to comment, so I am stuck misusing the answer function, but have you tried running

> ant -verbose

it might give you a more useful error to work with.

Good Luck!